# Using FFT as a black box to solve subset sum. How is this done? Given a set of numbers, S, and a target value T

Tags: algorithms, divide-and-conquer, subset-sum, polynomial-time-reductions, fast-fourier-transform

Given a set of numbers, S {s1, s2, ... sn} and a value T, I am looking to determine if any three elements in the set add up to value T. It is valid to have repeats like 2+2+2 would be fine for achieving a goal value of T=6.
This is ultimately a decision problem of whether such a trio of values exists within the set that add up (with allowing repeats) to the target value.

The goal is to use FFT as a blackbox for solving the problem. I am at a complete loss here.
How can FFT be used as a black box to solve subset sum?

Comment: Looks like a homework problem to me.

Comment: Hint: Think in terms of polynomial multiplication.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami I am understanding the FFT and polynomial multiplication but I don't understand how this maps to subset sum

Answer (score 3):

For a set $S = \{s_1,\dotsc,s_n\}$. Construct a polynomial $P(x): x^{s_1} + x^{s_2} + \dotsc + x^{s_n}$.

Multiply the polynomial by itself three times, i.e., $P(x) \cdot P(x) \cdot P(x)$. Let this polynomial be $Q(x)$

**Claim:** The coefficient of $x^T$ in $Q(x)$ is non-zero if and only if there exist three values in $S$ that sum to $T$.

**Proof:** [You may want to try it by yourself]

Comment: Thanks so much!